# inline expansion in excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell A1 containing text "XYZ", and another worksheet called XYZ. I am looking for a formula something like `=@[A1]!C3` where `@` is an inline expansion operator, so the formula evaluates to `=XYZ!C3`. I think this is called inline expansion or macro expansion (not to be confused with excel macro's). I thought Excel once had such an operator (maybe pre-VBA), but I can't find any trace of it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are looking for a solution using the INDIRECT function.

Try using this to create the reference you are looking for:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!"&"C3")
```

This will reference the contents of cell A1 to populate the sheet name and then will return the contents of cell C3 on the referenced sheet.

Hope that helps.